# PhpStorm code auto completion in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, phpstorm

I have a controller in CakePHP 2.2 application.
I use PhpStorm 4.0.1 as IDE.

In MyController.php file I declare this:

```
/**
 * @property MyUtilComponent $MyUtil
 */
```

1. Inside my controller, when I write `$this->` I can select "MyUtilComponent" from drop down list. [image]
2. But when I write `$this->MyUtilComponent->` no function name option comes to select. [image]
3. When I write `$this->MyUtil->addThis();` and then click to `addThis` word and "Go to declaration", then PhpStorm goes to method's declaration successfully.

What should I do more to get function names autocompletion ?

Note: The behaviour is same for the core components.

Comment: You should try newer version (v6 will be out in 2-3 months) -- I think it was fixed since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your PHPStorm. Version 5.0.4 is currently released and works the way you want it.